# How can I disable xDB?

Tags: configuration, xdb

If I don't have a working connection to MongoDB and I don't want to use xDB functionality. Currently, my logs are being filled with errors.

What is the configuration needed to disable xDB?

Comment: what is the sitecore version ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**For Sitecore 8.1 and later:**

Per Sitecore documentation, you can run in "CMS-only" mode:

> To run CMS-only mode, you must set the Xdb.Enabled configuration setting to false in the Sitecore.Xdb.config configuration file.
>   https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/experience_management/experience_management_an_overview

**For Sitecore 8.0:**

There is a knowledge base [article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/296641) describing how to run Sitecore 8.0 without MongodDB, listing these steps:

> Configuration Instructions To Disable XDB
>
> Step 1: Disable analytics:
>
> Go to /App_Config/Include/Sitecore.Analytics.config and set Analytics.Enabled to false:

```
<setting name="Analytics.Enabled" value="false" />
```

> Step 2: Comment out analytics related connection strings:
>
> Go to /App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config and comment out, or remove, the following connection strings:

```
<add name="analytics" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/analytics" />
<add name="tracking.live" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_live" />
<add name="tracking.history" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_history" />
<add name="tracking.contact" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_contact" />
<add name="reporting" connectionString="user id=user;password=password;Data Source=(server);Database=Sitecore_Analytics" />
```

The process is not as clean (for example, the system writes error messages to the log), and the KB article documents how Sitecore functionality is impacted.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up pre-8.1 and post-8.1 configuration settings. In the past, it was `Analytics.Enabled`, these days it's `Xdb.Enabled`.

Comment: I took this directly from Sitecore documentation, and I do make this distinction. I will improve the formatting to call it out better, however.

Comment: I see what you mean now! Yes, reformatting will help.

Comment: Done! I also corrected Sitecore's typo. The doc has "Xdb.enabled", but the actual setting is "Xdb.Enabled", as you point out. I figured it made more sense to show the correct setting then copy Sitecore's mistake.

Answer (score 16):

Starting from Sitecore 8.1, the settings that disable xDB have changed.

The settings are now located in `Sitecore.Xdb.config`. There are two boolean settings:

- `Xdb.Enabled` — if you set this to `false`, Sitecore will not store any data in MongoDB.
- `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` — if you set this to `false`, there will be no in-memory tracking of website users and their actions.

Using these two settings, you can fine-tune the way in which you want to disable marketing, tracking and reporting functionality.

Please refer to the official documentation for more information:

[**The CMS-only mode configuration settings**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up__maintaining/experience_management/configuring/configure_experience_management)

[**CMS-only mode compatibility**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up__maintaining/experience_management/configuring/experience_management_compatibility)

[**Disabling xDB and the Xdb tracker**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up__maintaining/experience_management/configuring/disabling_xdb_and_the_xdb_tracker)

(please note that there is an error on the above page: the setting is actually called `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled`, not `Xdb.Tracker.Enabled`)

Comment: Links are 404'ing

Answer (score 3):

Please note, as the KB article describes, that disabling the xDB will limit the functionality of your Sitecore installation, not only with regards to Experience Analytics. Certain features will be unavailable, e.g. the rules engine (even for non-analytics based rules).

Also, certain modules (WFFM) requires an xDB connection unless you implement a custom data store for form submission data.

Comment: Sitecore 8.1 now comes with a SQL data store for form results, and you can set the config to use `sqlFormsDataProvider` instead: https://citizensitecore.com/2016/05/11/wffm-and-cms-only-mode-in-sitecore-8-1/

Answer (score 0):

`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\[local]\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.xDB\Sitecore.Xdb`

Set these 2 values to false:

```
<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="false" />
<setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" value="false" />
```