# Package installation hangs on Sitecore 8.1

Tags: installation

I've encountered an issue on Sitecore 8.1 when installing Sitecore PowerShell Extensions. The same issue is happening for other larger packages as well.

This is a vanilla installation. No instance of Mongo Db running.

### Update

Adjusted the question to reflect to proper version of Sitecore. Turns out it was 8.1 and not 8.0.

Comment: If you don't have Mongo installed, have you explicitly turned off analytics and ip lookups?

Comment: I attempted the installation immediately following the Sitecore installer.

Comment: I've seen issues like this (packages not getting installed) when Mongo is not running. Have you tried again with a local Mongo instance for the sake to removing it as a possible cause for the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The requirement is to not use Xdb. I'll check to see if disabling it helps.

Comment: I wonder if the indexer is running while your install is still running. Maybe try disabling it during the installation. http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/sitecore_installation_wizard_disable_search_index_update_during_install/. When I was installing big, 100 mb, packages, I had this issue a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Refer to the following:

https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/troubleshooting.html (edited)

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/296641

Use this patch config:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
 <sitecore>
   <settings>
     <setting name="Xdb.Enabled">
        <patch:attribute name="value" value="false" />
     </setting>
     <setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled">
       <patch:attribute name="value" value="false" />
     </setting>
   </settings>
 </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

Turns out there is quite a bit to consider with this one. Disabling the Analytics and Xdb are two separate tasks that need to be performed depending on the version of Sitecore.

I ended up creating a new patch.

### Sitecore 8.1

**Company.Xdb.Config**

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Xdb.Enabled">
         <patch:attribute name="value" value="false" />
      </setting>
      <!-- Only disable tracking if you don't need it. Leave enabled if you want to personalize within the session. -->
      <setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled">
        <patch:attribute name="value" value="false" />
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

### Sitecore 8.0

**Company.Analytics.config**

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Analytics.Enabled" set:value="false"/>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Other useful links to provide details.

- Sitecore Stack Exchange

  - [Personalisation rules without xDB](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4767/is-it-possible-to-use-any-personalisation-rules-without-xdb/4769#4769)
  - [Disable xDB](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/342/how-can-i-disable-xdb/357#357)
- StackOverflow

  - [SO - Disable Analytics in Sitecore 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105370/disable-analytics-in-sitecore-8)
- Sitecore KB

  - [Disabling Analytics](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/296641)
  - [Disabling Xdb](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up__maintaining/experience_management/configuring/configure_experience_management)
  - [Disabling xDB and Tracker](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/experience_management/configuring/disabling_xdb_and_the_xdb_tracker)
- [Hanging Installation Wizard with SPE](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/troubleshooting.html)

Comment: This is the most complete answer.  Interestingly enough, I've seen this behavior go away immediately after an app-pool recycle as well.  Obviously not safe for production :)

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it is. Wanted to give Akshay the credit since it solved my problem. I just took what he had and enhanced the detail.

Comment: I also didn't even notice that you asked the original question, so there's that...

Comment: You don't have to disable `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` btw, otherwise you will lose the ability to carry out "session based personalization"

Comment: Really JammyKam? Do you have a link with more detail about it?

Comment: You can read more in [this answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/357/135) and [this answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/4769/135).

Comment: More details in the official documentation: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/experience_management/configuring/disabling_xdb_and_the_xdb_tracker