# Personalization Conditions not Executing - Intermittently working

Tags: personalization

I have some personalization conditions. None of these seem to execute. When debugging, none of the rules stop with break points. I have tried using the most simple built in rules such as `when [date] has passed` to no avail. It is just not stepping through the conditions.

This is on **Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 160729)**

I have values `Xdb.Enabled` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` set to `true`.

I am testing in normal mode. I have `Sitecore.xDB.base` license.

I see nothing in logs.

Below are the control properties and personalization rules. If the control does not have a data source nothing shows.

[image: Control Properties]

[image: Personalization Rules]

I have seen all of the custom rules execute correctly. This is the only rule that I have not seen execute correctly. Possibly if there is one rule that is incorrect it would stop personalization running altogether?

```
public class AptifyMemberDuesPaidThruCondition<T> : OperatorCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
{
    private readonly IAptifyAuthenticator _aptifyAuthenticator;

    public AptifyMemberDuesPaidThruCondition() : this(ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IAptifyAuthenticator>())
    { }

    public AptifyMemberDuesPaidThruCondition(IAptifyAuthenticator aptifyAuthenticator)
    {
        _aptifyAuthenticator = aptifyAuthenticator;
    }

    public string DuesPaidThru { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function will be called to test the condition
    /// </summary>       
    protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
    {

        //Check if the user is logged in, otherwise return false
        if (!_aptifyAuthenticator.UserAptifyAuthenticated())
            return false;

        DateTime dateTime = DateUtil.ParseDateTime(this.DuesPaidThru, DateTime.MinValue);
        if (dateTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc)
        {
            string str = string.Concat("AptifyMemberDuesPaidThruCondition<T> expects UTC date, but date with different kind has been assigned to Now property: ", this.DuesPaidThru);
            Log.Warn(str, this);
        }

        var actualDuesPaidThru = _aptifyAuthenticator.GetUserCustomerPropertyDate(AuthenticatedPropertyName.DuesPaidThru);

        if (!actualDuesPaidThru.HasValue)
            return false;

        return DateComparer(actualDuesPaidThru.Value, dateTime, GetOperator());

    }

    private bool DateComparer(DateTime date1, DateTime date2, ConditionOperator conditionOperator)
    {

        switch (conditionOperator)
        {
            case ConditionOperator.Equal:
                return date1.Equals(date2);
            case ConditionOperator.LessThan:
                return date1 < date2;
            case ConditionOperator.LessThanOrEqual:
                return date1 <= date2;
            case ConditionOperator.GreaterThan:
                return date1 > date2;
            case ConditionOperator.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                return date1 >= date2;
            case ConditionOperator.NotEqual:
                return !date1.Equals(date2);
            default:
                return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Any ideas where to troubleshoot?

> **Update**: this started working after I went to web database, modified a
>   property (not related to personalization) and saved the item. This
>   indicates some other kind of issue.
>
> **Update 2**: it stopped working with no changes. I can change the item
>   and see changes, but personalization is now not working. It is like it
>   just turns off.

Comment: Do you test in normal mode? Rules are not executed in edit or preview

Comment: I am testing in normal mode.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of your rule configurations and some code snippets of your config and/or any custom rule actions you've defined?

Comment: Added screenshots. Shows built-in rule not working.

Comment: Is the component which holds the rules cached?

Comment: Components are not cached as of now. Item is not cached. I can see other changes. It is like personalization is turning on/off.

Comment: The most common cause for custom rules not executing, is their class definitions and method signatures. Please share your code for the custom condition. E.g. see here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5168/whenconditiont-rule-custom-code-not-firing

Comment: I do not think it can be class definitions and method signatures given that these execute intermittently. Also this applies to the built in classes such as Sitecore.Rules.Conditions.DateTimeConditions.NowCondition.

Comment: Added a method (the only method that I have not been able to validate that it works correctly). Is it possible that one problem definition could break personalization altogether?

Comment: Do you have Sitecore cache enabled for this component (output cache)?

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue on my instance. The code was returning true/false correctly but the rendering was not updated in Sitecore.

Interesting, the rules started working when I disabled the tracking of personalization
[image]

Comment: Strange but, it worked!

Comment: I do not believe this option is available in Sitecore 9.0.2 so I am trying to figure out what I would do instead...

Answer (score 0):

The sitecore default rules are supposed to be executed without additional steps.
You can check the following to troubleshoot further.
1. Is the personalization rendering added to shared renderings section or final rendering section?
2. Did you publish the page and if so check the web database to see if the personalization rendering is present in web database.

Comment: Personalization rendering is in final rendering section. Personalization is in web database.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore default Rules execute without any custom code but if you want to write your own Rules then you can use below:

public class AptifyMemberDuesPaidThruCondition : WhenCondition where T : RuleContext

However there can be many reasons for this issue.
Refer:

[Is it possible to use any personalisation rules without xDB](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4767/is-it-possible-to-use-any-personalisation-rules-without-xdb)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue and I figured out that it worked when I changed from Experience Editor to Preview mode.