# WhenCondition not executing Sitecore 9.2

Tags: rules-engine

**Sitecore 9.2**

I'm trying to create a rule and execute a script but I can't execute my code from the Script reference.

My objective is to show Form B instead of Form A when the script returns true.

**Here's my rule:**

[image]

Here's the content that I want to show when the condition is true:

[image]

Here's my script (I added the namespace and assembly)

[image]

**And here's the code:**

[image]

My instance and the project are already deployed, so what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think what you're building should be a `WhenCondition`, which is also the direction your code is taking. Have a look here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5168/whenconditiont-rule-custom-code-not-firing

Comment: And then there's the usual; make sure you've installed a Sitecore XP (not just an XM).

Comment: @MarkCassidy, I have Sitecore XP, also I have xdb.enabled and xdb.tracking.enabled

Comment: I made two sentences.... :P

Comment: I suggest you checking HTML caching settings for your component and disable them if it is cached. I noticed a break change in Sitecore 9.2. If caching is enabled for the component and the same component is personalized, the personalization will not work any more. Before Sitecore 9.2 that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please update your code as below:

```
public class Evaluatecanada<T> : StringOperatorCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
{        
    protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
    {            
            return true;           
    }
}
```

I have faced the same issue but in my code, I have inherited it with `StringOperatorCondition` instead of `WhenCondition`.

You can find more details here [Custom Personalization Rules in Sitecore 9](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2019/05/customize-personalization-rules-in-sitecore-9.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but still I the script doesn't execute :(