# Tracker.Current is not initialized

Tags: xdb, wffm

In a clients setup we have one CD server and one CM server. When submitting a WFFM form on CD website, these errors occur in the CM log files:

```
ManagedPoolThread #16 14:23:22 WARN  [WFFM] Tracker.Current  is not initialized 
ManagedPoolThread #16 14:23:22 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\Anonymous): [WFFM] Form {59696292-85EB-473C-AACE-2105DEC99AB3} is saving to db
ManagedPoolThread #16 14:23:22 WARN  [WFFM] Tracker.Current.Contact  is not initialized
ManagedPoolThread #16 14:23:22 WARN  [WFFM]  Tracker.Current.Interaction  is not initialized
ManagedPoolThread #16 14:23:22 WARN  [WFFM] CurrentSession  is not initialized
```

Is this something to worry about? How might one solve this issue?

**Update**

This was marked as an duplicate, but the linked question/answer does not resolve my issue.
But i can see why you would think that.

This blog post https://sitecorehacker.com/2017/02/12/sitecore-analytics-tracker-common-issues-and-how-to-resolve-them/ does have some good information, but it does not explain why the messages above occur in relation to WFFM.

Comment: Try checking the following post. 
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8566/wffm-currentsession-is-not-initialized-filling-up-logs.  If that does not solve your issue, I'd recommend opening a case with Sitecore.